# od --width=x option isn't working. My path seems to be correct.

Tags: linux, bash, path

This is in my .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

But when I run:

```
od –-width=10 image.ppm
```

I get the message "od: –width=10: No such file or directory"

Is there something wrong with my path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you pasted the `--width` option from something that improved the double-dash at the beginning of the option.  That should be two ASCII `-` (minus-sign) characters.

Pasting from your example command, the actual character is u+2013 rather than u+002d